# How to save output to variable in Perl

Tags: perl, powershell, variables

I have a Perl script that passes an argument to powershell and returns the data to Perl. That value is stored, but i would like to assign that value to a variable and I'm not sure how to do so.

```
sub getvalue{
print "Getting value...\n";
my $renamecmd = 'Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File  C:\Workspace\Utilities\pathtofile.ps1'." $val"; 
my @output = `$renamecmd`;
foreach (@output) {
return $_;
}
}  

$newvar = $_;
```

What I have above does not work.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You return the first element of `@output` in that loop. That means it stops processing the loop, because it returned. Because `@output` is lexical to the sub, it is then lost. But since your code does not call the `getvalue` sub, that doesn't really matter, because it's never executed anyway. Your assignment of `$newvar = $_` will assign something to `$newvar` (which is a horrible variable name btw). Please show your **real** code.

Comment: This is my real code, but i've changed names of some items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution.

```
sub getValue{
    print "Getting value...\n";
    my $renamecmd = 'Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File C:\Workspace\Utilities\pathtofile.ps1'." $var";
    my @output = `$renamecmd`;
    $newvar= $output[3];
}
```

Again this is just a mockup, with terrible variable names.